# Unable to Boot Windows 8 after installing ubuntu in pendrive

Tags: installation, boot, usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu on my 32GB pen-drive which is a clean installation.After installation I unplugged my pen-drive now I cannot boot in to windows.

It says grub rescue.

What do I do.?

Answer (score 0):

Did you *install* Ubuntu on the flash drive, like it was a hard drive in your computer, or did you put the installer on it? If you installed Ubuntu on your flash drive, and either the installer or you screwed something up, get a *Windows* installation disk, and follow this guide: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-bootloader-over-gnu-grub-bootloader/2dd62280-c7e1-43b1-95df-89e86c346ca1 If you just put the installer on a flash drive, then I have no idea how your bootloader got replaced, but follow that guide anyway.

It says GRUB rescue, because the thing that loads windows got replaced by the thing that loads linux and *can* load windows, but the two bootloaders cannot coexist on the same drive, so you need to choose one or the other. GRUB just happens to be setup wrong to load windows, so it's the bootloader that gets deleted.